# Jquery live success ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have this code I am using for ajax,

```
 $('body').ajaxStart(function() {
$(this).after('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + $(window).height() + 'px;"></div>'); 
$('#lightBox').hide().show('scale');
```

});

And in ajax requests I am trying to do something like this with the success callback,

```
success: function() {
        $('#lightBox').after('<div style="background: ' + mainBg + '; color: ' + pageText + '; border: 1px solid ' + borders + '; "><h3 style="background: ' + headerBg + '; color: ' + headerText + '; border-bottom: 1px solid ' + borders + ';">Color Scheme Saved<img id="lightBoxClose" class="toolTips" src="" height="17" width="17" alt="" title="Close" /></h3><p>Your custom color scheme has been saved.</p></div>');
        $('#lightBox div').hide().show('scale');
    }
```

But as the `#lightBox` is live jquery, jquery does not fire the success callback, I understand how `.live` works in jquery but not in ajax calls...

Thanks

EDIT

On `ajaxStart` a div covers the whole screen. In other ajax requests I want to be able to add html content inside the div that `ajaxStart` has added to the DOM. Jquery will not add it as I do not know how to make the success callback function for ajax calls add things to live DOM elements.

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to do, it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see .live() anywhere in your code, I think .live is depreciated now and you should be using .on() - see http://api.jquery.com/on/. 
I dont quite understand your question -  .on/live makes actions available within the given scope regardless of changes in content such as ajax calls. if the scope of your .on call is body then as long as you do not replace the actual body tag, your functions will reference any element of that id/class which are created/changed. You can even apply accross the whole document if you need to replace the whole body for some reason.

If you are adding content to an html element which is created via ajax as part of the success callback function you do not need to use live or on, since the element is present and correct at the time of the callback.

If you had something like this in your javascript before the ajax call:

```
$('body').on("click", "#ajax_created_div", div_click);
```

The function div_click would be called every time the newly created div of id="ajax_created_div" was clicked.

Hope this clears thing up for you... otherwise I think your question needs a bit more detail... or I'm a muppet